# Error updating a file .csv using the library iostream

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to update the information from a file that is separating the data with ";" and "/", my problem is that when I execute the code, if(is.good) return false bring me an error.

This is a piece of the file.cpp that make the mistake in the mention part:

```
void VuelaFlight :: cargaVuelos(std::string &fichVuelos){
    std::ifstream is;
    std::stringstream columnas;
    std::string fila;

    Fecha _fecha;

    std::string _flightNumb = "";
    std::string _dep_airport_code = "";
    std::string _arr_airport_code = "";
    std::string _plane = "";
    std::string _datoMeteo = "";
    std::string _dia = "";
    std::string _mes = "";
    std::string _anio = "";

    is.open(fichVuelos); //carpeta de proyecto
    if (is.good()) {
        getline(is, fila);  //linea cabecera
        while (getline(is, fila)) {

            //¿Se ha leído una nueva fila?
            if (fila != "") {

                columnas.str(fila);

                //formato de fila: id;iata;tipo;_nombre;latitud;longitud;continente;iso_pais

                getline(columnas, _flightNumb, ';');
                getline(columnas, _dep_airport_code, ';');
                getline(columnas, _arr_airport_code, ';');
                getline(columnas, _plane, ';');
                getline(columnas, _datoMeteo, ';');
                getline(columnas, _dia, '/');
                getline(columnas, _mes, '/');
                getline(columnas, _anio);

                _fecha.asignarDia(stoi(_dia),
                                  stoi(_mes),
                                  stoi(_anio));

                registrarVuelos(_flightNumb,
                                _dep_airport_code,
                                _arr_airport_code,
                                _plane,
                                _datoMeteo,
                                _fecha);

            }
        }

        is.close();

    } else {
        throw std::ifstream::failure("VuelaFlight :: cargaVuelos-> Error de apertura en archivo");
    }
}
```

This is a little piece of the file that I'm trying to opening:

```
flightNumber;dep_airport_code;arr_airport_code;plane;dep_weather_desc;dep_date
HTY134;AEI;JCU;AWH;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
HTY110;JCU;AEI;AWH;Lluvia;13/04/18
HTY112;AEI;JCU;AWH;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
HTY114;AEI;JCU;AWH;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
HTY138;AEI;JCU;AWH;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
HTY133;JCU;AEI;AWH;Lluvia;13/04/18
HTY109;JCU;AEI;AWH;Lluvia;13/04/18
HTY111;JCU;AEI;AWH;Lluvia;13/04/18
HTY113;JCU;AEI;AWH;Lluvia;13/04/18
HTY137;JCU;AEI;AWH;Lluvia;13/04/18
IBE0519;LCG;MAD;AIRBUS A319;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
TAP1085;LCG;LIS;ATR-42/72;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
AEA7234;LCG;MAD;EMBRAER ERJ-195;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
IBE0513;LCG;MAD;AIRBUS A320;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
VLG1274;LCG;VLC;32A;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
VLG1298;LCG;SVQ;AIRBUS A320;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
AEA7236;LCG;MAD;EMBRAER ERJ-195;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
IBE0523;LCG;MAD;AIRBUS A320;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
VLG1295;LCG;BCN;AIRBUS A320;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
VLG7104;LCG;LHR;AIRBUS A320;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
LZF440;BIO;LCG;ATR 42-300/320;Lluvia;13/04/18
AEA7238;LCG;MAD;EMBRAER ERJ-195;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
VLG1303;ALC;BCN;32A;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
AEA4025;ALC;PMI;ATR-72;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
RYR4019;ALC;CPH;BOEING 737-800 WINGLETS;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
RYR8287;ALC;BRS;BOEING 737-800 WINGLETS;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
BEL3772;ALC;BRU;AIRBUS A320;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
JAF5358;ALC;BRU;7M8;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
EWG9533;ALC;DUS;32A;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
IBK5414;ALC;DUS;BOEING 737-800 WINGLETS;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
ANE8391;ALC;MAD;BOMBARDIER CRJ-1000;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
JAF5842;ALC;CRL;BOEING 737-700 WINGLETS;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
EZY8660;ALC;LGW;AIRBUS A319;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
ENT520;ALC;BUD;BOEING 737-800 WINGLETS;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
TRA6144;ALC;AMS;BOEING 737-800 WINGLETS;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
TRA6626;ALC;EIN;BOEING 737-800 WINGLETS;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
TRA5052;ALC;RTM;BOEING 737-700 WINGLETS;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
VLG1392;ALC;MXP;32A;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
VLG1374;ALC;AMS;AIRBUS A320;Nubosidad variable;13/04/18
IBE8213;LEI;PMI;CANADAIR CRJ-200;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
EZY8164;LEI;LGW;AIRBUS A320;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
IBE8595;LEI;MAD;BOMBARDIER CRJ-1000;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
RYR8352;LEI;STN;BOEING 737-800 WINGLETS;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
VLG1252;LEI;BCN;AIRBUS A320;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
IBE8577;LEI;MAD;BOMBARDIER CRJ-1000;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
IBE8589;LEI;MAD;CANADAIR CRJ-200;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
IBE8601;LEI;MAD;BOMBARDIER CRJ-1000;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
GMI2381;LEI;DUS;BOEING 737-700 WINGLETS;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
RYR1259;LEI;CRL;BOEING 737-800 WINGLETS;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
IBE8932;LEI;SVQ;CANADAIR CRJ-200;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
IBE8603;LEI;MAD;BOMBARDIER CRJ-1000;Chubascos dispersos;14/04/18
LGL694;LEI;LUX;BOEING 737-800 WINGLETS;Chubascos dispersos;14/04/18
JAF6944;LEI;BRU;EMBRAER 190;Chubascos dispersos;14/04/18
IBE0514;MAD;LCG;AIRBUS A319;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
VLG1292;BCN;LCG;32A;Lluvia moderada;13/04/18
AEA7233;MAD;LCG;EMBRAER ERJ-195;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
IBE0512;MAD;LCG;AIRBUS A320;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
VLG1299;SVQ;LCG;AIRBUS A320;Lluvia;13/04/18
AEA7235;MAD;LCG;EMBRAER ERJ-195;Chubascos dispersos;13/04/18
```

I tried to delete and reupdate the file, make it a reference cause' the others files that I'm using are references, deleting the if(is.good()) to see if the file opened and the file didn't opened so here I am.

Comment: One possibility: you are passing a relative path to `cargaVuelos`, but the current working directory is not what you think it is, so the file is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the global path of the CSV file not the relative one.